# Is there a way to know if LastModifiedDate field was change since the creation?

Tags: apex, trigger, update, createddate, lastmodifieddate

I have a requirements where I need to know if the record was never been updated since the creation. I tried comparing the lastModifiedDate or SystemModStamp and createdDate if equals, however they have a different value in slight differences. I need to know exactly if it the record was ever change. As much as possible I want to avoid using trigger or creating new field. I hope someone can help.

Comment: How were you comparing them?

Comment: I use the == sign. I also check the values in a query, the datetime is not exact even when it was never updated.

Comment: How do you wanna know whether a record is edited or not? By looking at the record page? or you want to query all the records which was never edited?

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your case, you can compare using the `getTime` method from `Datetime` [class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_getTime)

```java
Account acc = [ SELECT id, LastModifiedDate, CreatedDate FROM Account LIMIT 1];
System.debug('acc.LastModifiedDate --> ');
System.debug( acc.LastModifiedDate.getTime() );

System.debug('acc.CreatedDate --> ');
System.debug( acc.CreatedDate.getTime() );

System.debug('diff  --> ');
System.debug( acc.LastModifiedDate.getTime() - acc.CreatedDate.getTime() ); // this results in 0
```

If this subtraction is not equals zero, then chances are that some automated process modified the record after the creation.

Also, I think that is not soo good to compare with `SystemModStamp`, [because](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387261&type=1)

> Some Salesforce internal backend processes will also update 'SystemModstamp,' as 'SystemModstamp' is used internally to signal that a record, or related data, may have changed - and that internal processes may need to synchronize themselves to the new record data.

Comment: This goes against OP's request to avoid using a trigger (which I interpret as any Apex whatsoever). It's fine to present a "frame challenge" like this, but when you do you really ought to explain _why_ you're going against OP's wishes.

Comment: Well... It wasn't so clear to me how OP wanted how to accomplish this request, but I think that SystemModStamp is only accessbile through APEX or API (which could imply in use Apex). Also, I wasn't sure if avoid Trigger meant avoid using Apex, I imagined that maybe could be used inside a Batch or a simple method receiving a list of Ids to run in Execute anonymous (OP says if the record was ever modified, not any record). So I was trying to give a solution in, kind of, the same way OP was going to